# GoogleDrive file(s) as source for BQ External Table

Tags: google-bigquery

The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources#querying_data_from_google_drive is ambiguous as it suggests that it might be possible to create a BQ external table over a set of CSV files in a google drive folder but the examples given use gs:// URLs that suggest perhaps that the docs are copied and pasted from the GoogleStorage section further up the page. Could someone confirm if it is possible to create a table over 2 or more files in a google drive (as a wildcard) rather than only over a single file?

and to summarise then:

External Table over Google Storage Bucket: 0-n files
External Table over GoogleSheets Document: 1 file
External Table over GoogleDrive Object: 1 file?

TIA, Mark

BTW the BQ failure messages/diagnostics, even via the Jobs UI are utter pants :(

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the link from the browser of a Google Sheet and choose

`Location: Google Drive`
`File Format: Google Sheet`

and build the schema.

[image]

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't clear. I can create a table based on a single Google Sheets doc (first tab only, natch). What I want to know is, am I able to create a single external table that references multiple CSV files uploaded into a GoogleDrive folder?

Comment: Multiple files is not possible with GooglDrive. If you want to load in multiple files you need to use the gsutil shell utility and use * when you mention files in Google Cloud (GCS).

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems that (thanks Pentium10) it is only possible to reference a single file when using Google Drive or Google Sheets as the source of an external table. External tables can be defined to load from wildcarded files in a Google Storage Bucket (watch out for encoding UTF-8 is what's needed as I just found out after poring over absolutely useless BQ error messages, even in the Jobs UI)...

Thanks, M

Comment: This is not a forum, you should not post Answers to your own questions.